# .bind() .live() not working in Safari or Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am very new to this. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

I've got my website mostly working the way I want in Firefox, but now that I try test it in Safari or Chrome, it doesn't work. I'm sure there will be many more problems later, but the first issue is that I am dealing with is my main nav buttons are not working. The click handlers and `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` are not working.

Is there something wrong with this code or could it be a problem somewhere else?

```
function onLoad () {
    var $list= $('#mainNavList');
    showMainMenu(); //make menus appear 
    specifyScrollingElement('#mainNavList');
    specifyScrollingElement('#lowerNav');
    $list.find('.linkInactive').live('click', onMainNavMenuClick);
    $('.albumLink').parent().bind('mouseenter',function(){
      $(this).css({'background-color': '#fff'});
      });

     $('.albumLink').parent().bind('mouseleave',function(){
          if ($(this).hasClass('current')==false){
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(233,229,194,.9)'});
          };
     });

    $('.textLink').parent().bind('mouseenter',function(){
      $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(65,65,65,.8)'});
      });         
     $('.textLink').parent().bind('mouseleave',function(){
        if (portfoliosActive ==false && $(this).children().hasClass('portfolioButton')==true ){
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
          };
        if (portfoliosActive ==true && $(this).children().hasClass('homeButton')==true){
             $(this).css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
          };
    }); 
    $list.find('.linkActive').live('click',function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.addClass('linkInactive').removeClass('linkActive');         
          hideThumbs($list);
    });                   
    thumbnailActions('#mainNavList');
    thumbnailActions('#lowerNav');
    initUpperNavActions();  
}
```

Comment: A superb idea would be to make your sample work in a sandboxed area like http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar. This way you can change framework versions with impunity.

Comment: thanks Joe, I will read up about this. It is above my head right now. What is js fiddle and waht is a framework? Is jquery a framework?

Comment: Yes jQuery is a framework written in javascript. :)  jsFiddle: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/jsfiddle-an-online-playground-for-your-javascript-html-css/#.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'on' instead of 'bind' and 'live'... that should save you a world of pain later.
Those methods are deprecated as of jquery 1.7..

See the follow link for more info: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching
event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is
used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are
attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those
elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible
event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().
```

and also:  http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach
event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate()
in preference to .live().
```

And example of using 'on' for your code would be:

```
$('.albumLink').parent().on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#fff'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I tried replacing the .bind and .live with .on and also tried .delegate, but doesn't seem to work. When I try that it doesn't work in firefox for me anymore and still doesn't work in Safari. 

This is probably a dumb question, but I probably need to use a newer version of jquery, right? But if I do that is that going to mess up what I have working now? I understand that commands get deprecated as with new versions, but how come if i am using an older version of it, these deprecated scripts won't work? How come it works in Firefox but not the other browsers?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a newer version on jquery to use 'on' and 'live'. Use 1.9 and above...also, try to always to stay just one version behind at most, give some space for them to perfect the current version. Glad to see you figured it out though!

Answer (score 0):

You should use .on() it binds and persists. I use it in chrome with no issues.

```
$(".albumLink").on('click', function () { 
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(65,65,65,.8)'});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ 
if you are using an older jQuery you might have to use delegate() 
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

** NOTE: delegate switches the parameter order. In later Jquery (1.7) .delegate() is just an alias for .on() anyway

hth

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get on or delegate to work. I think I am still confused about how to use jquery.

But I figured out what the problem was with my click and mouseenter and mouseleave not working. I discovered an extra `"</div>"` in the code so I think there was an invisible div blocking my nav buttons. After I deleted it, the buttons all suddenly work in Safari and Chrome! Thanks for your time!